# Extract particular data fields from a scanned document in java

Tags: java, field, ocr, document, extract

How to extract particular **data fields from a scanned document** in java ? eg: in a scanned document, there are fields like;

```
            Name  : ABC 
            Place : XYZ
```

Now we need to fetch the values ABC,XYZ and copy into our java variables. 
Please help me through this.

Comment: try with regular expressions

Comment: What kind of document? Are you looking for an OCR library?

Comment: yes but which is the best OCR that can be used in this case

Comment: Please give the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Properties:

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new StringReader(data));
    String name = p.getProperty("Name");
    String place = p.getProperty("Place");
```

Comment: thank you, that would really help. But can you suggest a best method to convert the scanned document(mostly image format or pdf) into string.